# PHP foreach on nested array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am doing a GET php function on a URL and I get back the resulting response in JSON:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "text": "The 2014 BICSI Canadian Conference and Exhibition in Vancouver,    British Columbia, Canada is 61 days away on April 27 - 30.",
        "createdAt": "2014-02-  24T19:54:08.707Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-02-24T19:54:08.707Z",
        "objectId": "ZZrZ9OgyRG"
    }, {
        "text": "Only 33 more days fro the 2014 BICSI Canadian Conference and Exhibition in Vancouver, Canada!",
        "createdAt": "2014-03-24T13:23:56.240Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-03-24T13:23:56.240Z",
        "objectId": "ZqxJRiHoJo"
    }]
}
```

I am able to do php `json_decode` and display the results below on a web page like below

```
text | The 2014 BICSI Canadian Conference and Exhibition in Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada is 61 days away on April 27 - 30.

createdAt | 2014-02-24T19:54:08.707Z

updatedAt | 2014-02-24T19:54:08.707Z

objectId | ZZrZ9OgyRG

text | Only 33 more days fro the 2014 BICSI Canadian Conference and Exhibition in Vancouver, Canada!

createdAt | 2014-03-24T13:23:56.240Z

updatedAt | 2014-03-24T13:23:56.240Z

objectId | ZqxJRiHoJo
```

The php code I used to display the results above on the web page is:

```
$returned_content = get_data('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Alerts');

$data = json_decode($returned_content, true);

foreach ($data as $array1 => $arrayn) {
    foreach ($arrayn as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $t => $s) {
            echo"<p> $t | $s ";
        }
    }
}
```

If I just wanted to display the 'text' key/value info only on the web page, how should I modify the php. Meaning all I want to see displayed on the web page is:

```
text | The 2014 BICSI Canadian Conference and Exhibition in Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada is 61 days away on April 27 – 30.

text | Only 33 more days fro the 2014 BICSI Canadian Conference and Exhibition in Vancouver, Canada!
```

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: Thought I did... sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data->results as $item) {
    echo '<br>text | '.$item->text;
}
```

If you don't add the second `json_decode()` paremeter, you can just use your JSON with the StdClass.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside a simple if condition.

```
foreach ($data as $array1 => $arrayn) {
    foreach($arrayn as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $t => $s) {
            if($t == 'text') {
                echo"<p> $t | $s ";
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
$returned_content = get_data('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Alerts');

$data = json_decode($returned_content, true);

foreach ($data as $array1 => $arrayn) {
foreach($arrayn as $k => $v){
foreach ($v as $t => $s)
{
if($t == "text")
echo"<p> $t | $s ";
}
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line :

```
$data = json_decode($returned_content, true);
```

You have an associative array, so you can change your loop to :

```
foreach ($data as $array1 => $arrayn) {
    foreach($arrayn as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $t => $s) {
            if('text' === $t) {
                echo"<p> $t | $s ";
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple and with a check if the key exists, just in case the JSON does not contain the key "text" it will return notice.

```
$data = json_decode($str,true);
foreach($data["results"] as $key=>$val){
    if(array_key_exists("text",$val)){
        echo 'text | '.$val["text"];
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Here `$str` is your json string.